# How can I find multiple occurrences of a substring in another and do 'some' operations?

Tags: c, string

Here I am trying to find a substring in a string, reverse the substring and replace it in the original string. It works for the first occurances if I replace the while loop with an if condition. But I want it to work for multiple occurances.
If I am running it in a while loop(while(str=strstr(str,substr)), its causing  segmentation fault. I am using codeblocks IDE.
SO, how can I alter the code so that it can work for multiple occurances?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
char *str = malloc(100);
char *sbstr = malloc(20);
int i=0,flag=1;;
printf("%s\n","Enter string");
gets(str);
printf("%s\n","Enter substring");
gets(sbstr);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

while(str = strstr(str,sbstr))
    {

        memcpy(str,strrev(sbstr),strlen(sbstr));

    }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: When you use `strncpy()`, it adds a null terminator at the end of the copied string. Since you're copying into the source string, you've truncated the string to that point.

Comment: Before I even try to dive into your code, have you stepped it through a debugger such as GDB? Valgrind is also a useful tool to check for memory leaks. Also, be sure to compile with `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: Use `memcpy()` instead of `strncpy()`, so it doesn't add a null terminator.

Comment: Also, when you loop you should do the new search starting after the old match. Otherwise you can get an infinite loop if you're searching for a palindrome, because it will be unchanged after you reverse it.

Comment: Be sure to have a matching `free()` for _every_ `malloc()` (or `calloc()`, `realloc()`, etc.).

Comment: @Barmar I think the loop is going infinite. but unable to find a solution

Comment: You should also use `int main(void)` and `return 0;` at the end of `main()` ;). Also, you should **never** use `gets()`! ["`gets()` doesn't allow you to specify the length of the buffer to store the string in. This would allow people to keep entering data past the end of your buffer"](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/gets.html), use `fgets()` instead. And there's no reason why you can't just `printf("Enter string\n");` :P.

Comment: I can see you have responded to one of the commenters suggestions by editing a line in your post from `strncpy()` to `memcpy()`.  (and in other places as well)   It is not recommended to do this as it results in a moving target for those trying to answer the question.  Just acknowledge you understand the comment with another comment, or if in an answer, up-click the answer if it helped.

Comment: @RastaJedi, realloc does not require free by itself.

Comment: I could point you bugs (there are more than one), but you SHOULD FIND THEM YOURSELF.  Use debugger, or debugging print.  Unless you know how to debug code, any other programming skills are almost useless.

Answer (score 0):

Better and more efficient loop that works would be: (Look on it carefully)

```
char* first_p; //will store the address of the first character of sbstr in str if it does  


while(i < LENGTH_OF_STR) //if smaller than the length of the main array
{

    if(str[i] == sbstr[k])
    {  
        k++: 
        if(k == LENGTH_OF_SBSTR)
        {
           //sbstr is in str 
           first_p = str+i-LENGTH_OF_SBSTR-1; //now first_p stores the pointer to the first letter
           reverse(first_p,LENGTH_OF_SBSTR);// reversing the string 
           break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        k = 0; 
    }

    i++;

}

void reverse(char *toReverse,int len)
{   
    int i;
    char temp;

    for (i=len-1; i >= len/2; i--)
    {
        temp = toReverse[i];
        toReverse[i] = toReverse[len-1-i];
        toReverse[len-1-i] = temp;
    }

 }
```

Comment: Vote for the post if you think it helped :).